# Need help choosing which random variable distribution to use

Tags: distributions, discrete-distributions

I have these two questions.

> A department store claims that 80% of its customers pay their credit card on time. If you want to calculate the probability that at least 6 out of 11 customers pay their card on time, what type of distribution do you suggest to use?

In this one, I'm almost sure that is the binomial distribution with
P[X>=6] n=11 p=0.80.

But then there's this question.

> In the previous problem, if you now want to calculate the probability that between 60 and 75 customers pay their card on time, what distribution would you use?

Here I'm pretty confused because I think it can also be binomial subtracting F(75) - F(60). Am I approaching this question right?

Comment: Would that be btw 60 and 75 **out of 100**? If so, the exact answer from R, where `pbinom` is binomial CDF, would use code `diff(pbinom(c(59,75), 100, .8))` to get
$ 0.1313519.$ However, if this is a technophobic text or course, the intended answer might be 'normal', anticipating you'd standardize and use printed tables of the standard normal CDF. Then you can expect about 2-place accuracy: $0.13$ (because use of the table often requires rounding).

Comment: Please tag as [tag:self-study].